# which is more grammatically correct on date 26/6 or in date 26/6?

Tags: grammaticality

which is more grammatically correct to say on date 26/6 or in date 26/6 ?

I am using the on as a preposition and I feel not sure about that.

Comment: **In** 1974, **in** week 12, **in** December. But **on** Friday, **on** the 12th. And of course **at** 4 o'clock. I _guess_ it may have to do with whether the given time is considered a _specific moment_ (at 4), a _short period_ (on Friday) or a _longer period_ (in 1974). Leaving this as a comment as I have nothing but my own authority to back me up on this.

Answer (score 0):

The proper preposition with days is `on`. Usually people say `he was born on Friday 13th` or `he was born on 26/6`. There is no need for `date`.